# How to add a tkiz node to a knitr R chunk?

Tags: r, knitr, tikz

I want to draw a tikz path from the surrounding LaTeX into an R plot, for example an arrow from somewhere in the surrounding text to somewhere inside the plot region. So I want to add a tikz node or coordinate to a plot within an R chunk in knitr and draw a path to that. But knitr makes the graphics first, via tikzDevice, and then includes them, so I think this breaks "remember picture" and I can't do what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: it is possible, but not straightforward at the moment; there are two approaches -- one is possible in the current version of knitr (see the section "Manually Saved Plots" in the [knitr graphics manual](http://bit.ly/114GNdP)); the other is on my [todo list](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/561)

Comment: I can't understand the "too broad" close vote.